# systemd/init bind to port

Tags: systemd, bind, gps

I'm having a problem starting GPSD on a Beaglebone Green.  I get a socket bind error:

```
root@BBG1:/etc/init# gpsd -D3 -n -N /dev/ttyUSB0
gpsd:INFO: launching (Version 3.16)
gpsd:ERROR: can't bind to IPv4 port gpsd, Address already in use
gpsd:ERROR: maybe gpsd is already running!
gpsd:ERROR: can't bind to IPv6 port gpsd, Address already in use
gpsd:ERROR: maybe gpsd is already running!
gpsd:INFO: command sockets creation failed, netlib errors -1, -1
```

It appears the issue is common on these mini dev boards (Raspberry Pi included) but what seems to fix the problem for most people hasn't worked for me.  Near as I can tell, it's because `systemd/init` are beating gspd to it.

```
root@BBG1:/etc/init# netstat -lnpt
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2947            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/init
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      375/connmand
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      493/sshd
tcp6       0      0 ::1:2947                :::*                    LISTEN      1/init
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      631/apache2
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1/init
tcp6       0      0 ::1:53                  :::*                    LISTEN      375/connmand
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      493/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::1880                 :::*                    LISTEN      1/init
tcp6       0      0 :::3000                 :::*                    LISTEN      1/init
```

I've tried:

1. modifying `/lib/systemd/system/gpsd.socket` to change `ListenStream`from `127.0.0.1:2947` to `0.0.0.0:2947` but when I reboot, `init` binds to that instead (as seen in code block above).
2. `sudo killall gspd` and then restarting again, but that doesn't seem to help.
3. modify `/etc/default/gpsd` to the following:

   ```
   START_DAEMON="true"
   GPSD_OPTIONS=""
   DEVICES="/dev/ttyUSB0"
   USBAUTO="false"
   GPSD_SOCKET="/var/run/gpsd.sock"
   ```
4. a custom boot script in `/etc/rc.local` (supposed to delay the startup of gpsd, but it doesn't seem to be running because the startgpsd.txt file never updates)

   ```
   #Start the gpsd daemon
   /etc/booted/startgpsd.sh
   exit 0
   ```

which points to startgpsd.sh

```
    #!/bin/sh -e
    #Need to wait past boot so everything is done
    date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" > /startgpsd.txt
    sleep 2
    echo "Starting GPSD" >> /startgpsd.txt
    /usr/local/sbin/gpsd /dev/ttyUSB0 -G -n -F /var/run/gpsd.sock
    date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" >> /startgpsd.txt
    exit 0
    p
```

At one point when I upgraded GSPD from v 3.11 (downloaded with `apt-get`) to v 3.16 (downloaded the binary and a gig+ of other crap so I could build it) it started working, but as soon as I rebooted I was back to the same problem.

Is there a way to stop systemd from binding to the port so gpsd can instead (or is that even my problem)?  Killing PID 1 doesn't seem like a smart thing to do, so I haven't tried that yet.  I'm almost to the point of wiping everything and starting all over, but I thought I would try to harness the 'collective power of genius' here first (given that I've already found several answers to other problems here in the past).

Thanks!

Edit: Adding the contents of `/lib/systemd/system/gpsd.socket`

```
[Unit]
Description=GPS (Global Positioning System) Daemon Sockets

[Socket]
ListenStream=/var/run/gpsd.sock
ListenStream=[::1]:2947
ListenStream=0.0.0.0:2947
SocketMode=0600

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

Comment: Posting the contents of " /lib/systemd/system/gpsd.socket" would be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is that you have competing methods of trying to start gpsd and set up the second.

The first method you are using is `systemd` and `socket activation`. In this design, `systemd` sets up the second and waits for a connection to the socket. When something connects to the socket, `systemd` activates the service so it can respond. That's "socket activation". If you wish to use this approach, recommended reading includes [this blog post](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/socket-activation.html) about socket activation as well as the the official docs for [systemd socket files](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.socket.html).

The second method you are using is to start `gpsd` to run persistently via `rc.local` and to set up your own socket. This fails currently `systemd` has already tried to do this for you. If you wish to use this method and disable `systemd`, you can run:

```
systemctl stop gpsd
systemctl disable gpsd
```

I recommend using `systemd`. You don't have to use the socket activation feature if you don't want to. `systemd` can handle `gpsd` will handle restarting the daemon if it crashes, which your `rc.local` script does not do. `systemd` will also handle any logging that daemon might do, which your`rc.local` script doesn't handle either.

Comment: I now understand what `systemd` does, thank you.  I've commented out my `rc.local` script as it wasn't running anyway (the `startgpsd.txt` log never updated with new date and time unless I manually ran the script) and tried rebooting, but that didn't work (same result).  I also tried `systemctl stop gpsd` and `disable gpsd` and then running the gpsd command again, but got the same socket error and `netstat -lnpt` still shows `1/init` holding the port open.  Now that I understand what `systemd` is supposed to do, I'm left baffled at why it won't let `gpsd` use the port.

Comment: I've also noticed that when I use `cgps` (one of the tests that supposed to help determine `gpsd` functionality) the data stream down in the bottom has all the needed information (meaning the GPS antenna is working, has a fix, and is transmitting data) but the table won't populate with the information, which I thought was odd.  It can see it, but it won't use it.  Maybe the parsing is wrong?

Comment: Also try `systemctl stop gspd.socket` to shutdown the systemd-managed socket. I thought this would be done by shutting down the gpsd service, but maybe not.

Comment: Because I had made so many changes, I couldn't keep track of them all so I wiped and started from a fresh image. In rebuilding, I followed a tutorial for setting up GPSD for NTP (found [here](http://mythopoeic.org/beaglebone-green-time-server/)) which recommended disabling systemd (`systemctl disable gpsd.socket` and `systemctl stop gpsd.service`) and added `GPSD_OPTIONS="-n"` to `/etc/default/gpsd` so it would connect without waiting for a client first.  In `/lib/systemd/system` I edited `gpsd.service` to comment out anything calling the `gpsd.socket`. So you were right. Thanks!

Comment: hello, none of these worked for me. this is what allowed me to have the `gpsd` service installed, but stopped, and run another command-line instance of gpsd: `systemctl stop gpsd.socket`